# How can I bulk queue kafka messages to clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to bulk an Streaming queue kafka to clickhouse following the steps of official web page `https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/table_engines/kafka.html` and there is no way to make that it's run ok.

I've checked `kafka configuration` and it's ok because I've created a feeder for this queue and I've added to `clickhouse configuration` the `zookeeper's host` and `port`.

For example, the sentence from eclipse is :

```
System.out.println(ck.connection.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.clickhouseMd5 ("st1 String," + "st2 String," + "st3 String) ENGINE = Kafka('node2:2181', 'TestTopic', 'testConsumerGroup', 'JSONEachRow')"));
```

The result of `System.out.println()` is always *false* and there isn't exceptions.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

could you try run your query via commandline clickhouse-client 
on clickhouse node?

`cliclhouse-client -c "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.clickhouseMd5 (st1 String,st2 String, st3 String) ENGINE = Kafka('node2:2181', 'TestTopic', 'testConsumerGroup', 'JSONEachRow')"`

Comment: Hi, I've try while I  was writting messages in Kafka queue and the query is Ok but don't write records in clickhouse table. thank you.

Comment: could you run ```tcpdump -i any -w kafka_wtf.pcap port 2181``` on clickhouse server 
after that while you send message to kafka try runn query in clickhouse-client? anyphing captured ?
```telnet node2 2181``` working fine?

Comment: Sorry for reply lately, I've try the two commands that you said and both run ok but the problem persist. Using the command 'tcpdump -i any -w kafka_wtf.pcap port 2181' while I am writing in kafka queue, always capture the same xxxx bytes but anymore. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You use port 2181 which is a default port for zookeeper.
But according to documentation you mentioned (https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/table_engines/kafka.html) you should specify in the first argument a comma-separated list of brokers (localhost:9092).

Also note that it may not work with old Kafka version. For example with 0.9.0.1. With this version CREATE TABLE command returns OK. But in kafka logs I have error like 'ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18'.

But with the latest Kafka 0.11.0.2 it works fine for me.

Comment: You are right but I've try with differents ports (brokers port, zookeeper port.. etc) because I don't have broker in default port but there are no way. Thanks for your help.